# selenium TimeoutException on Linux/ chromium

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, serenity-bdd

I am getting a timeout error on the linux using chromium browser but same is working on the windows.

I am using the serenity BDD.

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for TransactionPage.moreTransactionButton to be not displayed (tried for 5 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'mesos-jenkins-9fd7a38e844041bcbcbf7079e094c3bc-java180u161-mave', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:304)
```

This is button  I am waiting for to get invisible.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//button[contains(.,'Show More Transactions')]", timeoutInSeconds = "180")
    public WebElementFacade moreTransactionButton;
```

**Edit 1:**

This is the waiting function

```
element(moreTransactionButton).waitUntilNotVisible().withTimeoutOf(Duration.ofSeconds(300));
```

Comment: Did you check on the screenshots whether the element is actually visible?

Comment: Yes , In the screen shot it is there. I am waiting for element to get in visible